# MediatR, generics and NET Core Dependency Injection - Cannot instantiate handler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, mediatr

I am building the app and trying to implement Domain Events with MediatR.
I am on .NET Core 2.1 (preview, but I do not think it is the issue) with MediatR 4.0.0

I am using the [example](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/tree/dev/src/Services/Ordering/Ordering.API/Application/Commands) of eShopOnContainers/Ordering service. They used Autofac, but I would prefer to stick with native DI container using [MediatR extension for that](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection)

My app crashed on startup. Error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type
>   'MyProject.API.Application.Commands.IdentifierCommandHandler`2[T,R]'
>   for service type
>
> > 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[MyProject.API.Application.Commands.IdentifiedCommand`> 2[T,R],R]'.'

My Nuget packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.1.0-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My app crashes on startup when trying to register IdentifiedCommandHandler:

```
public class IdentifiedCommandHandler<T, R> : IRequestHandler<IdentifiedCommand<T, R>, R>
        where T : IRequest<R>
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;
        private readonly IRequestManager _requestManager;

        public IdentifiedCommandHandler(IMediator mediator, IRequestManager requestManager)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
            _requestManager = requestManager;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the result value to return if a previous request was found
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected virtual R CreateResultForDuplicateRequest()
        {
            return default(R);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method handles the command. It just ensures that no other request exists with the same ID, and if this is the case
        /// just enqueues the original inner command.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">IdentifiedCommand which contains both original command & request ID</param>
        /// <returns>Return value of inner command or default value if request same ID was found</returns>
        public async Task<R> Handle(IdentifiedCommand<T, R> message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var alreadyExists = await _requestManager.ExistAsync(message.Id);
            if (alreadyExists)
            {
                return CreateResultForDuplicateRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                await _requestManager.CreateRequestForCommandAsync<T>(message.Id);

                var result = await _mediator.Send(message.Command);

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate any help on that.
I had to change it a bit to make it compatible with current MediatR, so I have IRequestHandler instead of IAsyncRequestHandler as it is not there anymore.

Comment: I think you are missing the mapping between your 'IdentifiedCommandHandler<T, R> ' and the actual implementations of T and R.

If you check the source, they use:
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CreateOrderCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));

Comment: But they are using autofac. I am using extension for native di

Comment: So you have to do it in the DI you are using. In core, you probably would do something like this:

services.AddScoped(typeof(IRequestHandler<>), typeof(IdentifiedCommandHandler<>));

Search for dependency injection of generic in dot net core that you will come up with a few articles related to it.

Comment: Take a look in this post, will help you with your issue:
https://codeopinion.com/fat-controller-cqrs-diet-simple-query

Comment: Judging from this discussion https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/471, this cannot be done with the built-in .NET Core container?

Comment: This nails the coffin... https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/531